# Can't get Json data to Ajax in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

Hi I'm trying to understand and implement Rails action controller with Ajax. My question is why I can't get Json data and display it to console.log in my Ajax function. I put my ajax function in application.js file. My ajax get method works fine but post method seems doesn't work. In article index page when you click new article it will render partial form and ajax will communicate with create action in controller to append data to index page. But I can't parse Json data to Ajax post.
Here are my code files:
**Updated image** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWg4g.png)
When I click create only json data in network tab show. Alert and console.log don't show anything.

application.js

```
$(function (){
var $article_table = $('#article_table');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/articles',
    success: function(articles){
        $.each(articles, function(i, article) {
            $article_table.append('<tr><td>'+article.name+'</td></tr>')
        });
    }
});
$('#form_article').submit(function(){
    //var name = $('#article_name').val();
    var name = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/articles',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: name,
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data.id);
            console.log('success',data);
            //debugger;
        },
        error: function(){

        }
    });
});
```

articles_controller.rb => in create controller I render article to json

```
   class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    #respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        #format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        #format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
        #format.html
        #format.json { render json: @article, status: :ok}
        render json: @article, status: :ok
      else
        #format.html { render :new }
        #format.html
        render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        #format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    #end
  end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
    <%= form_with(model: @article, remote: true , id: :form_article) do |form| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :article_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Articles</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="article_table">

  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Article', new_article_path, id: :new_article_link, remote: true %>
```

new.js.erb:

```
 $('#new_article_link').hide().after("<%= j render 'form' %>");
```

Comment: Are you sure that an article was saved? Maybe you have got an error? Add alert to error callback in js-file.

Comment: Where are you defining `xhr` in the following line from `application.js`? `var name = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: Hi @kunashir. Yup article was saved successfully when I refresh the page I could see new article added but I need to catch json data because I want to use ajax (I don't want to refresh the page). Thanks

Comment: Hi @SRack. Yes I tried that but doesn't work. I think maybe Ajax Post function doesn't get called because nothing show in console.log even I set "success" string in there.

Comment: @TranDuy Did you saw the response from server in browser? What do you receive?

Comment: @kunashir : this is response I get from Network tab. {"id":67,"name":"DFADF","created_at":"2018-01-31T01:10:14.025Z","updated_at":"2018-01-31T01:10:14.025Z"}.

Comment: how do I get that info and display it in console.log

Comment: I have one suggestion for your problem: `event.preventDefault();` in function for submit. Or try to make separate button - do not use submit!

Comment: thanks @kunashir. I will try and let you know

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the data like

`data: {article: {name: name}}`

On the jQuery/AJAX part see the below

```
$('#form_article').submit(function(){
    // Declare a variable for get data from input field
    var name = $('#article_name').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/articles',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {article: {name: name}},
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data.id);
            //console.log('success', data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            //debugger;
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I tried but in console.log still doesn't show data.

Comment: Make sure getting the value of input field like `alert(name);`

Comment: I added alert(name); but nothing show up. I already attached the image in the question. Only Network tab show Json data I can't catch that data and display it in console.log

Comment: Hey @TranDuy, try this `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: It's still the same. Nothing show in console .log. In console.log I have 'success' string even if It doesn't catch data but 'success' string is supposed to show in console log right?. Do you think the success function doesn't get called?